# Why does the looping in Google Sheet App Script stop in middle of the looping process and the rest of the codes do not run?

Tags: for-loop, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I tried the "for loop" and "do ... while ...", both of them stopped in the middle of the looping process, and the rest of the codes, which come after the loop, did not run. **This becomes an issue when I loop through hundreds of rows.**

*I know that the use of array is a better solution as the code execution is faster, but I have a difficulty in setting the borders in batch as there is no ".setBorders(Array)" function in Google Sheets.*

**The sheet provided here has been simplified only to show the looping issues. The actual sheet is written to automatically create hundreds of tables with different values, font weights and horizontal alignments.**

**What I want to do:**

1. Choose the option "Yes" to start the looping (the current row of looping is also tracked and recorded in "CURRENT ROW" and the "STATUS" shows "Processing ...")
2. The program will check the "SCORE" column, if "SCORE" is empty (""), than the font weight for that row is set to "bold", else, the font weight is set to "normal"
3. If the looping is done until the last row, the "STATUS" shows "Done".

**The following is the copy of the Google App Script:**

```
let app = SpreadsheetApp;
let ss = app.getActiveSpreadsheet();
let activeSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
let sheetName = activeSheet.getName();

let sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");

let loopOptionRange = sheet1.getRange(4, 4);
let loopOption = loopOptionRange.getValue();
let loopStatusRange = sheet1.getRange(4, 7);

function onEdit(e) {
}

function onOpen() {
  loopOptionRange.setValue("Choose");
  sheet1.getRange(4, 5).setValue(5);
  loopStatusRange.setValue("");
}

function loopTest() {
  const startRow = 4; //table head
  const lastRow = sheet1.getLastRow();
  sheet1.getRange(4, 6).setValue(lastRow);
  const startRowLoop = startRow + 1; //first row of looping

  try {
    for (i = startRowLoop; i <= lastRow; i++) {
      const testStatus = sheet1.getRange(i, 3).getValue();
      sheet1.getRange(4, 5).setValue(i);

      if (testStatus == "") {
        sheet1.getRange(i, 1, 1, 2).setFontWeight("bold");
      } else {
        sheet1.getRange(i, 1, 1, 3).setFontWeight("normal");
      }
    }

    loopStatusRange.setValue("Done");
    loopOptionRange.setValue("Choose");

  } catch (error) {
    app.getUi().alert(`An error occured.`);
  }
}

if (sheetName === "Sheet1"){
  if (loopOption == "Yes") {
    loopStatusRange.setValue("Processing ...");
    loopTest();
  } else if (loopOption === "Cancel") {
      loopOptionRange.setValue("Choose");
  }
}
```

[LOOP TEST - Google Sheets file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ihrFKBk_d0CjxHkNnO2LJR1IObIVsa3p-O3zjgSeQOw/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I saw your script, `getValue`, `setValue` and `setFontWeight` are used in a loop. In this case, the process cost will become high. I thought that this might be the reason for your issue. In order to reduce the process cost of your script, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
for (i = startRowLoop; i <= lastRow; i++) {
  const testStatus = sheet1.getRange(i, 3).getValue();
  sheet1.getRange(4, 5).setValue(i);

  if (testStatus == "") {
    sheet1.getRange(i, 1, 1, 2).setFontWeight("bold");
  } else {
    sheet1.getRange(i, 1, 1, 3).setFontWeight("normal");
  }
}
```

#### To:

```
const range = sheet1.getRange(startRow, 3, lastRow - startRowLoop);
const values = range.getDisplayValues().map(([c]) => [c ? null : "bold"]);
range.offset(0, -1).setFontWeights(values);
```

#### Note:

- About `Is it really because of "the high process cost" you mentioned in your answer?`, when I saw your script for the 1st time, I thought that the reason for your issue might be due to the process cost. Because, when the script is run by OnEdit trigger, the maximum execution time is 30 seconds. And, when I tested your script and your Spreadsheet, when I saw the log after the script was stopped, an error related to the over of the maximum execution time. By this, I resulted that the reason for your issue is due to the process cost of the script.

#### References:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [setFontWeights(fontWeights)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setfontweightsfontweights)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your codes work faster with no issues. I made some changes to your proposed codes so they produce exactly the same results as described in the questions, that is, the change of font weight should be done to column A, B, C not only column C, and if column C is empty the font weight should be "normal" not "null" to make sure that any previous font weight set in the cell is set to "normal".

Comment: **Here is the change:**
`const range = sheet1.getRange(startRowLoop, 3, lastRow - startRowLoop + 1);
const values = range.getDisplayValues().map(([c]) => [c ? "normal" : "bold"]);

range.setFontWeights(values);
range.offset(0, -1).setFontWeights(values);
range.offset(0, -2).setFontWeights(values);`
Thank you @Tanaike.

Comment: @Roby Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. From your reply and the current situation, I cannot understand whether your question was resolved. Can I ask you about the detail of it? If your issue was not resolved, I have to apologize for my poor skill and modify it.

Comment: hi @Tanaike, actually I have already got a solution for the looping issue before posting this question. Your solution worked faster than mine. To resolve the question on this page, can you confirm what causes the looping based on my codes stops in the middle of the process when there are hundreds of rows? Is it really because of "the high process cost" you mentioned in your answer? Is it a bug or does Google App Script set a limit to "the process cost"?

Comment: @Roby Thank you for replying. About `Is it really because of "the high process cost" you mentioned in your answer?`, when I saw your script for the 1st time, I thought that the reason for your issue might be due to the process cost. Because when the script is run by OnEdit trigger, the maximum execution time is 30 seconds. And, when I tested your script and your Spreadsheet, when I saw the log after the script was stopped, an error related to the over of the maximum execution time. By this, I answered it in my answer. If my answer was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: Please help to edit to include the following sentence in your answer and I will mark it as the Answer and resolve this question :) @Tanaike

`"Because when the script is run by OnEdit trigger, the maximum execution time is 30 seconds. And, when I tested your script and your Spreadsheet, when I saw the log after the script was stopped, an error related to the over of the maximum execution time."`

Comment: @Roby Thank you for replying. From your reply, I added it in my answer. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: Thank you @Tanaike, I have accepted your answer.

Comment: @Roby Thank you for your response. I will check your new question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245096/discussion-between-roby-and-tanaike).