# Why is batch operating in Google Sheets App Script such as "setFontWeights(Array)" function not working?

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets, batch-processing

I found out that there was an issue in my Google App Script. The use of `setFontWeights(Array)` function did not work. I did another test on `setValues(Array)` function and it did not work either.

**What I want to do:**

1. Choose the option "Yes" to start setting the font weights.
2. The program will check the "SCORE" column, if "SCORE" is empty (""), than the font weight for that row is set to "bold", else, the font weight is set to "normal"

**Issue:**
To test the error result, COMMENT line 46 to line 50 and UNCOMMENT line 53.
The codes from line 46 to line 50 are the current solution I have as line 53 does not work.

**The following is the copy of the Google App Script:**

```
let app = SpreadsheetApp;
let ss = app.getActiveSpreadsheet();
let activeSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
let sheetName = activeSheet.getName();

let sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");

let loopOptionRange = sheet1.getRange(4, 4);
let loopOption = loopOptionRange.getValue();
let loopStatusRange = sheet1.getRange(4, 7);

function onEdit(e) {
}

function onOpen() {
  loopOptionRange.setValue("Choose");
  sheet1.getRange(4, 5).setValue(5);
  loopStatusRange.setValue("");
}

function loopTest() {
  const startRow = 4; //table head
  const lastRow = sheet1.getLastRow();
  sheet1.getRange(4, 6).setValue(lastRow);
  const startRowLoop = startRow + 1; //first row of looping

  try {

    let textFormats = new Array(500);
    for (x = startRowLoop; x <= lastRow; x++) {
      const testStatus = sheet1.getRange(x, 3).getValue();
      textFormats[x] = new Array(3);
     
      if (testStatus == "") {
        for (y = 1; y <= 3; y++) {
          textFormats[x][y] = "bold";
        }
      } else {
        for (y = 1; y <= 3; y++) {
          textFormats[x][y] = "normal";
        }
      }
    }

    //LINE 46 to 50 WORKS
    for (x = startRowLoop; x <= lastRow; x++) {                   //LINE 46
      for (y = 1; y <= 3; y++) {                                  //LINE 47
        sheet1.getRange(x, y).setFontWeight(textFormats[x][y]);   //LINE 48
      }                                                           //LINE 49
    }                                                             //LINE 50

    //LINE 53 DOES NOT WORK
    // sheet1.getRange(startRowLoop, 1, lastRow - startRowLoop + 1, 3).setFontWeights(textFormats); //LINE 53

    loopStatusRange.setValue("Done");
    loopOptionRange.setValue("Choose");

  } catch (error) {
    app.getUi().alert(`An error occurred.`);
  }
}

if (sheetName === "Sheet1"){
  if (loopOption == "Yes") {
    loopStatusRange.setValue("Processing ...");
    loopTest();
  } else if (loopOption === "Cancel") {
      loopOptionRange.setValue("Choose");
  }
}
```

[BATCH OPERATING - ARRAY - Google Sheets File](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dGrYBttuxDk7h4K7_VYc2swxQPELFa7-FBx7CQxkRnI/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: How will you do your previous question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/72387186 And, about `I found out that there was an issue in my Google App Script. The use of "setFontWeights(Array)" function did not work. I did another test on "setValues(Array)" function and it did not work either.`, if you are saying for https://stackoverflow.com/q/72387186 , can you provide the detailed information about it? Because when I tested my proposed script, I cannot replicate `did not work`. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @Tanaike, sorry for the late response. I have written some comments for [stackoverflow.com/q/72387186](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72387186). For the question here on this page, I do not know why the setFontWeights function (LINE 53) give an error.

Comment: @Tanaike, It would be great if you can help to find out what mistakes I made in the script posted on this page?

Comment: How will you do your previous question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/72387186

Comment: @Tanaike, please check my comment on [stackoverflow.com/q/72387186](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72387186). I will accept your answer after you edit your answer to include some details. 

How about the question here on this page, do you know what mistakes I made in my script? I know that your solution works faster, but I want to know why LINE 53 does not work.

Comment: I have already replied. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: I proposed a modification point as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script, `let textFormats = new Array(500);` is declaread, and you are using this array in the loop of `for (x = startRowLoop; x <= lastRow; x++) {,,,}`. In this case, the top 5 elements are empty. And, each element of `textFormats` is created in the loop of `for (y = 1; y <= 3; y++) {,,,}`. In this case, each element has 4 elements. I think that in this case, an error occurs at `sheet1.getRange(startRowLoop, 1, lastRow - startRowLoop + 1, 3).setFontWeights(textFormats);`. I think that these are the reason of your issue.

When these points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### From:

```
let textFormats = new Array(500);
for (x = startRowLoop; x <= lastRow; x++) {
  const testStatus = sheet1.getRange(x, 3).getValue();
  textFormats[x] = new Array(3);
 
  if (testStatus == "") {
    for (y = 1; y <= 3; y++) {
      textFormats[x][y] = "bold";
    }
  } else {
    for (y = 1; y <= 3; y++) {
      textFormats[x][y] = "normal";
    }
  }
}
```

#### To:

```
var values = sheet1.getRange(startRowLoop, 1, lastRow - 4, 3).getValues();
var textFormats = values.map(([a,b,c]) => c == "" ? Array(3).fill("bold") : Array(3).fill("normal"));
```

- In this case, please use `sheet1.getRange(startRowLoop, 1, lastRow - startRowLoop + 1, 3).setFontWeights(textFormats);` instead of `for (x = startRowLoop; x <= lastRow; x++) {,,,}`.

#### References:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: @Roby Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I thought that in this case, you can also use `var textFormats = values.map(([a,b,c]) => Array(3).fill(c == "" ? "bold" : "normal"));` instead of `var textFormats = values.map(([a,b,c]) => c == "" ? Array(3).fill("bold") : Array(3).fill("normal"));`.

Answer (score 0):

If you reorganize it like this it seems to run okay but I only copied Sheet1

```
function onEdit(e) {
}
function onOpen() {
  loopOptionRange.setValue("Choose");
  sheet1.getRange(4, 5).setValue(5);
  loopStatusRange.setValue("");
}
//I ran this function with no errors
function myfunk() {
  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  let activeSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  let sheetName = activeSheet.getName();
  let sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  let loopOptionRange = sheet1.getRange(4, 4);
  let loopOption = loopOptionRange.getValue();
  let loopStatusRange = sheet1.getRange(4, 7);
  if (sheetName === "Sheet1") {
    if (loopOption == "Yes") {
      loopStatusRange.setValue("Processing ...");
      loopTest();
    } else if (loopOption === "Cancel") {
      loopOptionRange.setValue("Choose");
    }
  }
}
function loopTest() {
  const startRow = 4; //table head
  const lastRow = sheet1.getLastRow();
  sheet1.getRange(4, 6).setValue(lastRow);
  const startRowLoop = startRow + 1; //first row of looping
  try {
    let textFormats = new Array(500);
    for (x = startRowLoop; x <= lastRow; x++) {
      const testStatus = sheet1.getRange(x, 3).getValue();
      textFormats[x] = new Array(3);
      if (testStatus == "") {
        for (y = 1; y <= 3; y++) {
          textFormats[x][y] = "bold";
        }
      } else {
        for (y = 1; y <= 3; y++) {
          textFormats[x][y] = "normal";
        }
      }
    }
    for (x = startRowLoop; x <= lastRow; x++) {                   //LINE 46
      for (y = 1; y <= 3; y++) {                                  //LINE 47
        sheet1.getRange(x, y).setFontWeight(textFormats[x][y]);   //LINE 48
      }                                                           //LINE 49
    }                                                             //LINE 50
    sheet1.getRange(startRowLoop, 1, lastRow - startRowLoop + 1, 3).setFontWeights(textFormats); //LINE 53
    loopStatusRange.setValue("Done");
    loopOptionRange.setValue("Choose");
  } catch (error) {
    app.getUi().alert(`An error occurred.`);
  }
}
```

Comment: hi @Cooper, please review your codes. They do not work. Maybe there were some mistakes in copying and pasting. One of the errors is that LIne 46 to Line 50 must be commented when Line 53 is uncommented and vice versa.